# HIbernate-MySQL5Dialect wants to drop foreign key instead of index

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

We are using Hibernate (jboss 7.1.1 Version) with MySQL5Dialect. Our Database is "mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32".

The property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" is set to "create".

Nevertheless Hibernate isn't able to drop the tables at its startup phase. The first problem which can be found in the logs is the following:

```
08:40:53,520 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) Hibernate: alter table Item drop foreign key FK22EF33845529AC
08:40:53,527 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Item drop foreign key FK22EF33845529AC
```

Hibernate wants to drop a foreign key which cannot be found. The database has no foreign key with the given name, but an index with the given name. Dropping the index works without any flaw:

```
alter table Item drop index FK22EF33845529AC;
```

should we use another SQLDialect?

Answer (score 0):

We have set "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to "create-drop", so far it solves our problem.